# Mail Merging Photo ID's in Word 2010/2013

Tags: excel, ms-word, mergefield

I've been spending a number of days on this issue, and I would appreciate if someone can help.

I've got an Excel sheet of data fields, with a field containing the paths of photos that I would like to create an ID card Mail Merge onto Avery Labels.

I've been able to merge all the data I need using Word 2010 and 2013 with no issues, but the problems occur when attempting to include the photos.

The images themselves can merge just fine if brought alone, showing different images in different labels as desired.

However, it's when I try to position the image in a square layout -so that the data fields appear alongside the image on a label -as opposed to under it- that the process breaks down.

What happens is, only the first image gets pulled through, and it gets copied over to all the other labels (even when showing their different ID's in the labels, it's always the first image that gets copied throughout). I have tried saving the document and then pressing F9, tried saving it to XML as some have suggested then refreshing but no luck, it stays with only the first image being copied throughout.

In the document itself I use `{ INCLUDEPICTURE "{MERGEFIELD Photos}" }` with Photos being the name of the field in Excel containing the path. I have used different variations of this command, I've put the paths in the Excel sheet in between double quotes yet still the problem remains.

As soon as I try to change the layout of the photos so that the fields are displayed to the right of it, only the first image in the list comes through.

Has anyone encountered this or can help?

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately don't mention what technique you use to position the photos... However, I think the only way this can work is to add additional columns for each lable column, adjusting the column widths to that two columns are as wide as the original single column.

Put the IncludePicture fields with the Mergefields in the left-hand column, the other information in the right-hand column, along with the "Next" field.

Mail merge should then move to the next record every second column.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cindy, I position the photo using Word itself, I click on the first photo, then choose "Page Layout" from the menu, then click on the photo and choose "Square", the moment I do this the first label would have exactly the photo position and the fields but unfortunately when trying to update the other labels it stays stuck on the same photo!...      That said, I'll try your suggestion for now thanks again.

Comment: I suspected you were doing something like that. When text wrapping is applied to a graphic it's taken out of the "text layer" and then mail merge doesn't "see" it anymore. Just to explain why the approach doesn't work... :-)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct that's what was happening. However, I tried splitting the cells idea you mentioned, and it works beautifully for the first cell, trouble is, when I try to do "Update Fields" (to replicate the same thing for the rest of the document) it only takes the left cell (the one containing the photo) through, not the details on the right cell. I tried highlighting both then clicking update fields, but still, only the left most cell is copied through....    I'll keep experimenting though, it's getting there!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved my issue, and the way to do it was basically to create a table of 2 cells (not create 2 separate cells), and then populate the first cell with the photo info, and the second cell would have the personal information.

This made sure that when updating the fields it updated both cells ensuring the photos came through with their personal data.

So the steps are as follows:
1) Open MS Word

2) Choose Mailings-->Start Mail Merge--> Choose Label (in my case it was Avery 3653)

3) Choose Mailings-->Select Recipient List-->Point it to Excel File

4) *This is key* in the first Cell (or Label) in the document, Insert a Table made of 2 Cells.

5) Place the Photo info in the left Cell, the personal info on the right.

6) Click update fields to replicate the same format throughout the document.

9) Choose Finish&Merge-->Edit Individual Document.

10) Press CTRL-A, then F9, this will update all the document with the info from Excel, hopefully showing different photos with their corresponding personal data.